# Java Popsicle Immutable

Tags: java, concurrency, immutability

I am working on a problem where I need to load a large number of inputs to a problem, and process those inputs to create a 'problem space' (i.e. build data structures allowing efficient access to the inputs, etc). Once this initialization is complete, a multi-threaded process kicks off which uses the organized/processed inputs extensively in a concurrent fashion.

For performance reasons, I don't want to lock and synchronize all the read operations in the concurrent phase.  What I really want is an an immutable object, safe to access by multiple readers simultaneously.

For practical reasons (readability & maintainability) I don't want to make the InputManager a true immutable object (i.e. all fields 'final' and initialized in construction).  The InputManager will have numerous data structures (lists and maps), where the objects in each have many circular references to each other.  These objects are constructed as 'true' immutable objects.  I don't want to have a 14 argument constructor for the InputManager, but I do need the InputManager class to provide a consistent, read-only view of the problem space once constructed.

What I'm going for is 'popsicle immutability' as discussed by Eric Lippert [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability)

The approach I'm taking relies on using 'package visibility' of all mutating methods, and performing all mutable actions (i.e. construction of the InputManager) within a single package.  Getters all have public visibility.

Something like:

```
public final class InputManager {  // final to prevent making mutable subclasses 
    InputManager() { ... } //package visibility limits who can create one
        HashMap<String,InputA> lookupTable1;
        ...

    mutatingMethodA(InputA[] inputA) { //default (package visibility)
        //setting up data structures...
    }

    mutatingMethodB(InputB[] inputB) { //default (package visibility)
        //setting up data structures...
    }

    public InputA getSpecificInput(String param1) {
        ... //access data structures
        return objA; //return immutable object
    }
}
```

The overall idea, if I haven't been clear enough, is that I'll construct the InputManager in a single thread, then pass it to multiple threads who will do concurrent work using the object.  I want to enforce this 'two-phase' mutable/immutable object lifecycle as well as possible, without doing something too 'cute'.  Looking for comments or feedback as to better ways to accomplish this goal, as I'm sure it's not an uncommon use case but I can't find a design pattern that supports it either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd stay with your simple and sufficient approach, but in case you're interested, there is such a thing as a *mutable companion* idiom. You write an **inner class** that has mutators, while reusing all the fields and getters from the enclosing instance.

As soon as you lose the mutable companion, the enclosing instance it leaves behind is truly immutable.

Comment: Thanks all for the great answers.  Based on these answers, I looked at the guava ImmutableCollections implementations, and the 'builder' paradigm there seems very much like the mutable companion idiom you mention.  I'm looking at this, trying to decide if it's worth the effort at this point in the project.  Thanks!

Comment: Pretty good discussion of this here: (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11538/comments-on-my-java-pattern-for-mutable-turned-immutable-objects)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply have separate interfaces for your two phases. One for the building part, the other for the reading part. This way, you separate your access patterns cleanly. You can see this as an instance of the [interface segregation principle (pdf)](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf):

> Clients should not be forced to depend upon interfaces that they do not use.

Comment: I like the idea of the separate interfaces, and appreciate the pointer to the pdf. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the object is safely published, and the readers cannot mutate it.

"Publication" here means how the creator makes the object available to readers. For example, the creator put it in a blocking queue, and readers are polling the queue.

It depends on your publication method. I'll bet it's a safe one.

Comment: Appreciate the comment. I'll ensure the publication method is appropriate.